# fetch user specific data from tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to fetch only authenticated user specific data in Tastypie but don't know if I can use sessions or something to store user details. Below is my Code:

```
class PhonebookValidation(Validation):
    """Phonebook Validation Class"""
    def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):
        if not bundle.data:
            return {'__all__': 'Please enter data'}
        errors = {}
        if not 'name' in bundle.data or bundle.data.get('name') == '':
            errors['name'] = ['Please enter phonebook name.']
        return errors

class PhonebookResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Phonebook.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'phonebook'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        validation = PhonebookValidation()
        throttle = BaseThrottle(throttle_at=1000, timeframe=3600)

    def hydrate(self, bundle, request=None):
        bundle.obj.user = User.objects.get(pk=bundle.request.user.id)
        return bundle

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        return super(PhonebookResource, self).obj_create(bundle, user=bundle.request.user)

    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(user=request.user)
```

But it's still returning all user's data. Please guide me if I am doing it wrongly or suggest me some code/link to understand it.